# Powershell script : read and insert value from txt file (on 30+ entry)

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Sorry, i'm noob for powershell, but want to automate the following:

Got a powershell script:
**import-module ActiveDirectory
$username = Read-Host 'Please enter Username!'
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $username | Get-ADGroup -Properties * | select name, description**

When run script i enter the username and it give me a list which group the user is member of.

I had a big 50-100 list user list which obtained with **Get-aduser -filter * -properties Name | select-object Name | out-file -filepath .\userlist.txt** command and saved to a text file.
Is there any way to read every user 1 by 1 and auto fill the username field, then save the output to a text file? when finished with the 1st, script rerun and read the next value.

Is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: [1] Why not simply get all users and pipe these through to `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` ? [2] Your code eventually will only retrieve the name and description for each group, no user info is kept at all, so is this really what you want as output? In that case, why not just do `Get-ADGroup` and save that? [3] Never do `-Properties *` when all you want is the Name and Description property (btw. Name is returned by default, so `-Properties Description` woud suffice) [4] Why store the results with multiple properties in a plain text file when you would benefit more if you save it as CSV ?

Comment: Hi Theo, all i wanted to use this list for generate a member of info.  i can do it one by 1 , but got 143 user which take time.. if i can narrow it down with a script which basically goes through the list and add the username then write to a file, then goes to the next user do the same,,,

Comment: Note: you've exported the `Name` property to file; that's not the username, but the person's full name (and it's not unique).  You're probably more interested in the `samaccountname` field which is unique (there's also `UserPrincipalName which is unique, but doesn't work as an `-Identity` value so only queryable via `-filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$upnEscaped'"`; or there's `objectGuid`, `SID`, `distinguishedName` and a few other unique identifiers you could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a few snippets to help you put together what you need.

Get all users from a file containing only usernames

```
[string[]]$allUsers = Get-Content -Path '.\FileWithUsernames.txt'
```

Get all active users from AD

```
[string[]]$allUsers = Get-AdUser -Filter "enabled -eq 'True'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'SAMAccountName'
```

Loop through users getting the users' group info / doing something with it

```
foreach ($user in $allUsers) {
    Get-AdUser -Identity $user -Properties 'memberof' | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'memberof' |
        ForEach-Object {
            ([PSCustomObject]@{ Username=$user; GroupDN = $_})
        } |
        Export-Csv -Path '.\AllActiveUsersGroups.csv' -Append -Delimiter ',' -Encoding 'Utf8' #-NoTypeInformation #only include the -notypeinfomrmation parameter if using PS rather than PWSH)
}
```

Comment: Hi John, that works like charm after slight adjustment for the path. Many thanks. Did not realised the name issue for first, but now got it. Thank you